# How to return from a method with an inner class

Tags: java, android

I'm new to java and I have a method that I'm trying to use a wrapper for an async server call from Parse.com. I want to return a custom object containing the info I get back from the call, but I get the "error: unknown class"
basically I'm trying to prevent this method from returning until done() is called.

Im not sure how java would handle this kind of thing, I'm used to working in objective-C. Does anyone know how I can have the return statement not called until I set the properties in done() ?

```
public ServerResponse getRestaurauntProfile(){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> profileQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Restaurant");
    profileQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    profileQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    final ServerResponse mResponse = new ServerResponse();

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                mResponse.setReturnObject(list.get(0));
                mResponse.setReturnException(null);

            } else {
                mResponse.setReturnObject(null);
                mResponse.setReturnException(e);

            }

        }

        return mResponse;

    });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like AsyncTask might be a good approach for this (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: like @Nija said, put your async task in a an AsyncTask and do what you want in postExecute method

Comment: "I'm trying to prevent this method from returning until done() is called" - so you're trying to modify async behavior to sync (by making the call "blocking"). AFAIK Android does not allow blocking calls from a few versions back (Gingerbread - I think). You'll have to modify your code to async - by triggering the "post actions" from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent solution to this would be to utilize [Retrofit from Square](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). Retrofit is an excellent library for handling asynchronous network calls. As user alfasin said in the comments, you are trying to force an asynchronous method to act synchronously, which is a big no no in Android. if you want to continue using your current code structure, you can restructure it roughly like this:

```
public void getRestaurauntProfile(){ 

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> profileQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Restaurant");
    profileQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    profileQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    final ServerResponse mResponse = new ServerResponse();

        @Override 
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) { 
                mResponse.setReturnObject(list.get(0));
                mResponse.setReturnException(null);
                handleResponse(mResponse);
            } else { 
                mResponse.setReturnObject(null);
                mResponse.setReturnException(e);
                handleResponse(mResponse);
            } 
        } 
    }); 
}

public void handleServerResponse(ServerResponse mResponse){
    //do whatever code handling you need here
}
```